# Is it possible to disable pinch-to-zoom in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gesture

Eclipse Neon introduced [pinch-to-zoom](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#pinch-to-zoom).  I often trigger it accidentally and find it a very distracting interruption.  Is there a way to disable it?

(Even after practicing the not-very-intuitive gesture to recover the zoom, I still have a hard time remembering my place after it's zoomed in and out.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code (`initializeZoomGestures` in `org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor`) there does not appear to be any way to disable this.

Comment: Thanks for verifying- I've filed [bug 541713](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=541713).